# binning data in python with scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

is there a more efficient way to take an average of an array in prespecified bins? for example, i have an array of numbers and an array corresponding to bin start and end positions in that array, and I want to just take the mean in those bins? I have code that does it below but i am wondering how it can be cut down and improved. thanks.

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import *

def get_bin_mean(a, b_start, b_end):
    ind_upper = nonzero(a >= b_start)[0]
    a_upper = a[ind_upper]
    a_range = a_upper[nonzero(a_upper < b_end)[0]]
    mean_val = mean(a_range)
    return mean_val


data = rand(100)
bins = linspace(0, 1, 10)
binned_data = []

n = 0
for n in range(0, len(bins)-1):
    b_start = bins[n]
    b_end = bins[n+1]
    binned_data.append(get_bin_mean(data, b_start, b_end))

print binned_data
```

Answer (score 227, accepted):

It's probably faster and easier to use [`numpy.digitize()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
import numpy
data = numpy.random.random(100)
bins = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 10)
digitized = numpy.digitize(data, bins)
bin_means = [data[digitized == i].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))]
```

An alternative to this is to use [`numpy.histogram()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
bin_means = (numpy.histogram(data, bins, weights=data)[0] /
             numpy.histogram(data, bins)[0])
```

Try for yourself which one is faster... :)

Answer (score 55):

The Scipy (>=0.11) function [scipy.stats.binned_statistic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) specifically addresses the above question.

For the same example as in the previous answers, the Scipy solution would be

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

data = np.random.rand(100)
bin_means = binned_statistic(data, data, bins=10, range=(0, 1))[0]
```

Answer (score 17):

Not sure why this thread got necroed; but here is a 2014 approved answer, which should be far faster:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(100)
bins = 10
slices = np.linspace(0, 100, bins+1, True).astype(np.int)
counts = np.diff(slices)

mean = np.add.reduceat(data, slices[:-1]) / counts
print mean
```

Comment: you are answering to a different question. For example your `mean[0] = np.mean(data[0:10])`, while the right answer should be `np.mean(data[data < 10])`

Answer (score 6):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to efficiently perform operations of this type:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
print(npi.group_by(np.digitize(data, bins)).mean(data))
```

This is essentially the same solution as the one I posted earlier; but now wrapped in a nice interface, with tests and all :)

Answer (score 5):

I would add, and also to answer the question [find mean bin values using histogram2d python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917685) that the scipy also have a function specially designed to [compute a bidimensional binned statistic for one or more sets of data](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
values = np.random.rand(100)
bin_means = binned_statistic_2d(x, y, values, bins=10).statistic
```

the function [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd.html) is a generalization of this funcion for higher dimensions datasets

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use the ufunc.at. This method applies in-place a desired operation at specified indices.
We can get the bin position for each datapoint using the searchsorted method. 
Then we can use at to increment by 1 the position of histogram at the index given by bin_indexes, every time we encounter an index at bin_indexes.

```
np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.random(100) * 100
bins = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)

histogram = np.zeros_like(bins)

bin_indexes = np.searchsorted(bins, data)
np.add.at(histogram, bin_indexes, 1)
```