# Plotting log-binned network degree distributions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, networkx, scientific-computing

I have often encountered and made long-tailed degree distributions/histograms from complex networks like the figures below. They make the heavy end of these tails, well, very heavy and crowded from many observations:

[image: Classic long-tailed degree distribution]

However, many publications I read have much cleaner degree distributions that don't have this clumpiness at the end of the distribution and the observations are more evenly-spaced.

![image: Classic long-tailed degree distribution]

How do you make a chart like this using `NetworkX` and `matplotlib`?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? It looks like you've already achieved the result you are looking for. You'll need to be more specific than "make it better".

Comment: There's no question, just sharing how I solved a problem and opening it up to others' feedback if I've missed something in my approach.

Comment: The better way to do this, otherwise it will get closed, is to break this up into a question and answer it yourself. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: In this case you'll get feedback in the comments to the answer where they belong, as it stands now this question should be closed - but fix it since you've posted a lot of good information!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [log binning](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1533.pdf) ([see also](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1062.pdf)). Here is code to take a `Counter` object representing a histogram of degree values and log-bin the distribution to produce a sparser and smoother distribution.

```
import numpy as np
def drop_zeros(a_list):
    return [i for i in a_list if i>0]

def log_binning(counter_dict,bin_count=35):

    max_x = log10(max(counter_dict.keys()))
    max_y = log10(max(counter_dict.values()))
    max_base = max([max_x,max_y])

    min_x = log10(min(drop_zeros(counter_dict.keys())))

    bins = np.logspace(min_x,max_base,num=bin_count)

    # Based off of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163334/binning-data-in-python-with-scipy-numpy
    bin_means_y = (np.histogram(counter_dict.keys(),bins,weights=counter_dict.values())[0] / np.histogram(counter_dict.keys(),bins)[0])
    bin_means_x = (np.histogram(counter_dict.keys(),bins,weights=counter_dict.keys())[0] / np.histogram(counter_dict.keys(),bins)[0])

    return bin_means_x,bin_means_y
```

Generating a classic scale-free network in `NetworkX` and then plotting this:

```
import networkx as nx
ba_g = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10000,2)
ba_c = nx.degree_centrality(ba_g)
# To convert normalized degrees to raw degrees
#ba_c = {k:int(v*(len(ba_g)-1)) for k,v in ba_c.iteritems()}
ba_c2 = dict(Counter(ba_c.values()))

ba_x,ba_y = log_binning(ba_c2,50)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.scatter(ba_x,ba_y,c='r',marker='s',s=50)
plt.scatter(ba_c2.keys(),ba_c2.values(),c='b',marker='x')
plt.xlim((1e-4,1e-1))
plt.ylim((.9,1e4))
plt.xlabel('Connections (normalized)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

Produces the following plot showing the overlap between the "raw" distribution in blue and the "binned" distribution in red.

[image: Comparison between raw and log-binned]

Thoughts on how to improve this approach or feedback if I've missed something obvious are welcome.

Comment: for noobs, what are the x-y labels here?

Comment: The x-y labels are: x axis -> the log of the degrees encountered in the network; y axis -> the log of the frequency of those degrees.

Comment: Note - in many places `counter_dict.keys()` should be replaced by `list(counter_dict.keys())` for newer versions of python (for which `dict.keys()` is not a list)

Comment: Does it ever make sense to plot a degree distribution type plot like you have shown on data that isn't network data? That is, to use this plot over a histogram? Say on skewed blood pressure data or counts of something? thanks