# Fast way to turn a labeled image into a dictionary of { label : [coordinates] }

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

Say I've labeled an image with [scipy.ndimage.measurements.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) like so:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
 [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What's a fast way to collect the coordinates belonging to each label? I.e. something like:

```
{ 1: [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1]],
  2: [[4, 0], [4, 1], [5, 0], [5, 1]],
  3: [[3, 4]] }
```

I'm working with images that are ~15,000 x 5000 pixels in size, and roughly half of each image's pixels are labeled (i.e. non-zero).

Rather than iterating through the entire image with `nditer`, would it be faster to do something like `np.where(img == label)` for each label?

EDIT:

Which algorithm is fastest depends on how big the labeled image is as compared to how many labels it has. Warren Weckesser and Salvador Dali / BHAT IRSHAD's methods (which are based on `np.nonzero` and `np.where`) all seem to scale linearly with the number of labels, whereas iterating through each image element with `nditer` obviously scales linearly with the size of labeled image.

The results of a small test:

```
size: 1000 x 1000, num_labels: 10
weckesser ... 0.214357852936s 
dali ... 0.650229930878s 
nditer ... 6.53645992279s 


size: 1000 x 1000, num_labels: 100
weckesser ... 0.936990022659s 
dali ... 1.33582305908s 
nditer ... 6.81486487389s 


size: 1000 x 1000, num_labels: 1000
weckesser ... 8.43906402588s 
dali ... 9.81333303452s 
nditer ... 7.47897100449s 


size: 1000 x 1000, num_labels: 10000
weckesser ... 100.405524015s 
dali ... 118.17239809s 
nditer ... 9.14583897591s
```

So the question becomes more specific:

For labeled images in which the number of labels is on the order of `sqrt(size(image))` is there an algorithm to gather label coordinates that is faster than iterating through every image element (i.e. with `nditer`)?

Comment: `np.where(img == label)` (or equivalently `np.nonzero(img == label)`) will be faster than iterating through with `nditer`.  However, do you actually need the indices?  If you're wanting to extract values of some other array, `data[img == label]` will be faster than `i, j = np.where(img == label); data[j, j]`.

Comment: @JoeKington Turns out `np.where` will not always be faster than iterating. I just made some edits to my question that reflect this.

Comment: Did you eliminate the use of `np.unique` from Salvador Dali and BHAT IRSHAD's answers?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes

Comment: Related: [faster alternative to numpy.where?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33281957/7851470)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possibility:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
              [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# If the array was computed using scipy.ndimage.measurements.label, you
# already know how many labels there are.
num_labels = 3

nz = np.nonzero(a)
coords = np.column_stack(nz)
nzvals = a[nz[0], nz[1]]
res = {k:coords[nzvals == k] for k in range(1, num_labels + 1)}
```

I called this script `get_label_indices.py`. Here's a sample run:

```
In [97]: import pprint

In [98]: run get_label_indices.py

In [99]: pprint.pprint(res)
{1: array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1]]),
 2: array([[4, 0],
       [4, 1],
       [5, 0],
       [5, 1]]),
 3: array([[3, 4]])}
```

Comment: I think your method is the fastest of the proposed solutions, but I haven't done thorough testing yet. Surprisingly, for large numbers of labels (~30,000), it seems like iterating through each image pixel (~75,000,000 of them) ends up being faster. When I do some thorough comparisons I'll update my question with what I find.

Comment: Just got around to doing a more detailed comparison. Lemme know what you think.

Comment: @bennlich Nice comparison.  I suspected the performance would depend strongly on the density of the labels and on the number of unique labels.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (let `img` is your original nd.array)

```
res = {}
for i in np.unique(img)[1:]:
  x, y = np.where(a == i)
  res[i] = zip(list(x), list(y))
```

which will give you what you want:

```
{
 1: [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
 2: [(4, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 1)],
 3: [(3, 4)]
}
```

Whether it will be faster - is up to the benchmark to determine.

Per Warren's suggestion, I do not need to use unique and can just do

```
res = {}
for i in range(1, num_labels + 1)
    x, y = np.where(a == i)
    res[i] = zip(list(x), list(y))
```

Comment: Because `img` was computed using `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label()`, it is not necessary to call `np.unique(img)` to get its unique values.  We already know the values are 0, 1, 2, ..., `num_labels`.  `num_labels` is also known, because it is the second return value of `label()`.  So you could replace `np.unique(img)[1:]` with `range(1, num_labels+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> z
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> {i:zip(*np.where(z==i)) for i in np.unique(z) if i}
{1: [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], 2: [(4, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 1)], 3: [(3, 4)]}
```

Comment: Why do you need `if i` at the end of your comprehension?

Comment: See my comment to @SalvadorDali's answer about the use of `np.unique(img)`.  You could replace `for i in np.unique(z) if i` with `for i in range(1, num_labels + 1)`.

Comment: Oh, I see. The `if i` excludes the pixels labeled as 0s.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an `argsort` operation, with some additional work to get the desired format:

```
def sorting_based(img, nlabels):
    img_flat = img.ravel()

    label_counts = np.bincount(img_flat)
    lin_idx = np.argsort(img_flat)[label_counts[0]:]
    coor = np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(lin_idx, img.shape))

    ptr = np.cumsum(label_counts[1:-1])
    out = dict(enumerate(np.split(coor, ptr), start=1))

    return out
```

As you found out, doing `np.where(img == label)` for each label results in quadratic runtime `O(m*n)`, with `m=n_pixels` and `n=n_labels`. The sorting based approach reduces the complexity to `O(m*log(m) + n)`.

It is possible to do this operation in linear time, but I don't think it's possible to vectorize with Numpy. You could abuse the `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26888164), but at that point you're probably better off writing code that actually makes sense, in Numba, Cython, etc.