# numpy.where makes code slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have the following block of code:

```
def hasCleavage(tags, pair, fragsize):
    limit = int(fragsize["mean"] + fragsize["sd"] * 4)
    if pair.direction == "F1R2" or pair.direction == "R2F1":
        x1 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r1] >= pair.r1["pos"]) & (tags[pair.chr_r1] <= pair.r1["pos"]+limit))[0]
        x2 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r2] <= pair.r2["pos"]+pair.frside) & (tags[pair.chr_r2] >= pair.r2["pos"]+pair.frside-limit))[0]
    elif pair.direction == "F1F2" or pair.direction == "F2F1":
        x1 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r1] >= pair.r1["pos"]) & (tags[pair.chr_r1] <= pair.r1["pos"]+limit))[0]
        x2 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r2] >= pair.r2["pos"]) & (tags[pair.chr_r2] <= pair.r2["pos"]+limit))[0]
    elif pair.direction == "R1R2" or pair.direction == "R2R1":
        x1 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r1] <= pair.r1["pos"]+pair.frside) & (tags[pair.chr_r1] >= pair.r1["pos"]+pair.frside-limit))[0]
        x2 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r2] <= pair.r2["pos"]+pair.frside) & (tags[pair.chr_r2] >= pair.r2["pos"]+pair.frside-limit))[0]
    else: #F2R1 or R1F2
        x1 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r2] >= pair.r2["pos"]) & (tags[pair.chr_r2] <= pair.r2["pos"]+limit))[0]
        x2 = np.where((tags[pair.chr_r1] <= pair.r1["pos"]+pair.frside) & (tags[pair.chr_r1] >= pair.r1["pos"]+pair.frside-limit))[0]
    if x1.size > 0 and x2.size > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My script takes **16 minutes** to finish. It calls `hasCleavage` millions of times, one time per row reading a file. When I add above the variable `limit` a `return True` (preventing calling `np.where`), the script takes **5 minutes**.

`tags` is a dictionary containing numpy arrays with ascending numbers.

Do you have any suggestions to improve performance?

EDIT:

```
tags = {'JH584302.1': array([   351,   1408,   2185,   2378,   2740,   2904,   3364,   3657,
         4240,   5324,   5966,   5977,   5986,   6488,   6531,   6847,
         6961,   6973,   6991,   7107,   7383,   7395,   7557,   7569,
         9178,  10077,  10456,  10471,  11271,  11466,  12311,  12441,
        12598,  13051,  13123,  13859,  14167,  14672,  15156,  15252,
        15268,  15273,  15694,  15786,  16361,  17073,  17293,  17454])
}
fragsize = {'sd': 130.29407997430428, 'mean': 247.56636}
```

And `pair` is an object of a custom class
`<__main__.Pair object at 0x17129ad0>`

Comment: `np.where` constructs a new, potentially huge array. Given that you only need the size of that resulting array, this is probably not what you want, you could try iterating over the array and checking for the condition or using some other NumPy function instead.

Comment: A similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281957/faster-alternative-to-numpy-where