# Explanation for the code that returns indices of unique values in 1D NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I found this snippet of code online and am having difficulty in understanding what each part of it is doing as I'm not proficient in Python.

> The following routine takes an array as input and returns a dictionary that maps each unique value to its indices

```
def partition(array):
  return {i: (array == i).nonzero()[0] for i in np.unique(array)}
```

Comment: Was the description not descriptive enough? It finds the indices of each unique value and puts it inside a dictionary. That said, this is badly written code.

Comment: If there is a better way to do this, can you post it below?
I don't understand what this part is doing (array == i).nonzero()[0]

Comment: Is it actually the dictionary comprehension part you're having trouble understanding, rather than the numpy expression for each value that Coldspeed explained to you?

Comment: When I say "badly written", I mean from the viewpoint of readability. Performance wise, not sure it can get much better than this (you could probably cythonize a loop yourself, but really, would you bother?).

Comment: It is suboptimal because it needs to loop in the entire array as many times as there are unique values in the array. I suggest to loop in the array once and create the dictionary incrementally if there is nothing better.

Comment: Normally, when one wants an explanation of the code, it's preferable to split it to separate parts. In this specific case it's unclear if there is a problem with understanding dict comprehension, boolean masks, or some other NumPy functionality. I'm voting to close this question as *needs more focus*. See [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) for details.

Comment: For those who come here just to get the solution for getting the indices, see the [faster alternative to numpy.where?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33281957/7851470) post for a more general and, most probably, more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trace each part out, this should speak for itself. Comments inlined.

```
In [304]: array = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3])

In [305]: np.unique(array)            # unique values in `array`
Out[305]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [306]: array == 1                  # retrieve a boolean mask where elements are equal to 1
Out[306]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False])

In [307]: (array == 1).nonzero()[0]   # get the `True` indices for the operation above
Out[307]: array([0, 1, 5])
```

In summary; the code is creating a mapping of `<unique_value : all indices of unique_value in array>` -

```
In [308]: {i: (array == i).nonzero()[0] for i in np.unique(array)}
Out[308]: {1: array([0, 1, 5]), 2: array([2, 4, 6]), 3: array([3, 7])}
```

And here's the slightly more readable version -

```
In [313]: mapping = {}
     ...: for i in np.unique(array):
     ...:     mapping[i] = np.where(array == i)[0] 
     ...:     

In [314]: mapping
Out[314]: {1: array([0, 1, 5]), 2: array([2, 4, 6]), 3: array([3, 7])}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `array == i` Return a boolean array of True whenever the value is equal to i and False otherwise.
- `nonzero()` Return the indices of the elements that are non-zero(not False). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html
- `nonzero()[0]` Return the first index where array[index] = i.
- `for i in np.unique(array)` Iterate over all the unique values of array or in other words do the logic foreach value of unique value of the array.

Answer (score 2):

consider also the following Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd

In [165]: s = pd.Series(array)

In [166]: d = s.groupby(s).groups

In [167]: d
Out[167]:
{1: Int64Index([0, 1, 5], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([2, 4, 6], dtype='int64'),
 3: Int64Index([3, 7], dtype='int64')}
```

PS `pandas.Int64Index` - supports all methods and indexing like a regular 1D numpy array

it can be easily converted to Numpy array:

```
In [168]: {k:v.values for k,v in s.groupby(s).groups.items()}
Out[168]:
{1: array([0, 1, 5], dtype=int64),
 2: array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int64),
 3: array([3, 7], dtype=int64)}
```