# How to find the length of array within a tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple of arrays and need to find the length of an array by using the index of the tuple. This tuple is generated from a sparse matrix alternative to numpy where i'm using **scipy.sparse.csr**_matrix and **numpy.unravel_index** based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33286432/12904231)

ie:

```
>>>T = [(array([0,1,2,3,4,5]),), (array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),)]
>>>print(T[1])
(array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),)
```

I need to find the length of each array within the tuple for use later. using len() does not work

```
>>>len(T[1])
1
```

I am using this within a for loop that iterates through each array using those arrays as an index for other data.

I have searched and searched for how to solve this but found nothing. Please help!

Comment: Of course it won't work because `(array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),)` is a tuple that contains one item. Just try to access it: `len(T[1][0])`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: You don't have a tuple of arrays. You have a list of tuples of one array each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item in `T` is a tuple of length 1, so just index it, like this:

```
>>> len(T[1][0])
10
```

To be clear:

```
>>> T[1]
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
>>> T[1][0]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try comprehension concept as well,like

```
arr_length = [len(i[0]) for i in T]
```

Comment: *`len(i)` -> `len(i[0])` since `i` is a tuple