# Find center of blocks of ones in an 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

Lets assume I have the following array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]])
```

and want to get the center of each block of ones, so that I can get the following array:

```
a_centers = np.array([[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]])
```

I already thought about using means or convolutions, but I couldn't think of a really simple solution.

One in efficient solution that I found is:

```
a_centers = np.zeros(a.shape)

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if np.sum(a[i - 1:i + 2, j - 1:j + 2]) == 9:
            a_centers[i, j] = 1
```

Comment: Define a block.

Comment: are the blocks necessarily 3x3? square?

Comment: @ScottHunter I added a solution that I found but that seems to be inefficient.

Comment: Yes they should be always square

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012889/what-is-a-faster-way-to-get-the-center-points-of-objects-represented-in-a-2d-n . This is strangely the 3rd question posted since few hours on this (very?) specific topic.

Comment: What does "seems to be inefficient" mean?

Comment: I want to get rid of the two for loops and iterating over all values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little less inefficient, since no edge cell can be at the center of a 3x3 block:

```
for i in range(1,len(a)-1):
    for j in range(1,len(a[i])-1):
        if np.sum(a[i - 1:i + 2, j - 1:j + 2]) == 9:
            a_centers[i, j] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're sure your blocks are square and don't share cells, then you can skip all the `sum` stuff. and i do hope that `np.where` is faster than `for` loops

```
x,y=np.where(a==1)
blocks=list(zip(x,y))
for _ in range(x.size//9):
    left_x,left_y=blocks[0]
    a_centers[left_x+1, left_y+1]=1
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            blocks.remove((left_x+i, left_y+j))
```