# Binned scatterplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a simple way or a package for creating binned scatterplots in python?

I have a scatterplot. I am fitting a local polynomial regression to the data using the package "localreg". I get multiple lines as output. I am searching for a 1 line output. In order to get this I want to used a binned scatterplot. Is there no easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first bin your arrays, do your fitting and then create your plot.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html

Comment: How will you implement that exactly? I was thinking it should be possible to do it after I run the localreg? But how do I match my X and Y?

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26783719/13131172
binned_statistic returns bin numbers which you can use to slice your X array.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [hexabin plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) in Matplotlib, if this suits your purpose. Here is [an example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/hexbin_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-hexbin-demo-py). Here [another example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/hexbin_marginals.html) using seaborn.