# Numpy: binning boolean data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a one dimensional array of boolean value that I am trying to bin (averager over larger bins) in a way that if a bin is True if any of the values inside is True.

I have been trying to do it in the fashion of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712136/3275464

```
import numpy as N
data = N.random.randint(2,size=100).astype(bool) #generating array of random booleans
bins = N.linspace(0,100,11,1).astype(int) #the array containing the bins
binned_data = N.logical_or.reduceat(data,bins[:-1])
```

but the last line gives me the following error:

```
 TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

It seems to me that it should work just as it does with averaging.

I am using numpy 1.6.2 by the way.

Do you see where I am committing a mistake?

Comment: Are the bins always uniform in size or can the size vary between bins?

Comment: Is `slices` the same as `bins`? (If so, your code runs without error using NumPy version 1.8.2).

Comment: @TheBlackCat: they are all the same size except for the last one which may be shorter if `len(data)` not divisible by the bin width. the last bin can be shorter that the other ones

Comment: @unutbu: Yes, they are the same, just corrected, thank you. Okay then it may be a bug in my numpy version but I can't upgrade it sadly. Will have to go for another option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NumPy 1.8.2 your code works fine.

Since the error indicates a problem with safely casting the values to the required type, the problem seems to be related to the values in `data` being bools.

Therefore, a work around for earlier versions might be to cast the bools as ints,
do the `reduceat` computation on ints, and then recast as bools:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.1, size=100).astype(bool) 
bins = np.linspace(0,100,11,1).astype(int) 

expected = np.logical_or.reduceat(data,bins[:-1])
print(expected)
# [ True False  True  True False  True  True False False  True]

binned_data = np.add.reduceat(data.astype('int'), bins[:-1]).astype(bool)
print(binned_data)
# [ True False  True  True False  True  True False False  True]

assert (expected == binned_data).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the bins are always the same size, the simplest approach would be to `reshape` and then use `any` to find if any value in a row is `True`:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(2,size=100).astype('bool')
binned_data = data.reshape((5, -1)).any(axis=0)
```

If the bins aren't always the same size, the simplest approach would be to get the indexes of `True` values, then do a histogram, then find all the nonzero histogram bins:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.randint(2,size=100).astype('bool')
bins = np.linspace(0,100,11,1)
inds = np.where(data)[0]
binned_data = np.histogram(inds, bins=bins)[0].astype('bool')
```