# How to bin the sum of list values in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I need some help in binning my data values. Need a histogram-like function, but I don't want to list the occurrences, just the sum of the values for each bin.

In my example below I have a list with the number of Twitter followers for 30 days. Lets say I want 10 bins, then each bin would take the values of 30 / 10 = 3 days. For the first three days the value for bin 1 would be 1391 + 142 + 0 = 1533 for bin 2 12618, etc., up to bin 10.

The number of bins as well as the duration could eventually be varied. It also needs to work for a duration of 31 days and 5 bins, for instance.

Anyone knows how to do this efficiently? Is there a Python function available that could do this? Otherwise an implementation of a for loop that is able to sum n number of values in a list together until end of duration.

All help would be highly appreciated :) Thanks!

```
    followersList = [1391, 142, 0, 0, 12618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 456, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    duration = 30
    bins = 10
    binWidth = round(duration / bins)

    #
    # for loop or python function that sums values for each bin
    #
```

Comment: Check here for using numpy to solve this.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163403/4080476

Comment: We're not here to do your homework. Try something first, e.g. for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
bin_width = int(round(duration / bins))
followers = [sum(followersList[i:i+bin_width]) for i in xrange(0, duration, bin_width)]
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Don't have that much experience with list comprehensions. Now I'm able to feed the Twitter features to my machine learning models again :)

Comment: Is there no simplet solution to the problem provided by numpy, scipy or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing is by reshape and sum. I know that you already have a valid answer but you need to practice a lot with numpy list operations

```
import numpy

# this works when the list divides exactly into bins
followersList = [1391, 142, 0, 0, 12618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 456, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
duration = len(followersList)
bins = 10
binWidth = round(duration / bins)
print(numpy.array(followersList).reshape(bins, binWidth).sum(axis=1))

# otherwhise we have to pad with zero till its a multiple of containers
followersList = [1391, 142, 0, 0, 12618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 456, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
binWidth = 3
bins = (len(followersList) - 1) // binWidth + 1  # ceiling division
print(
    numpy.pad(followersList, (0, bins * binWidth - len(followersList)), 'constant').reshape(bins, binWidth).sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: Is there no simplet solution to the problem provided by numpy, scipy or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I thought that there should be some function provided by `numpy` or `scipy` to do this, but I couldn't find one. The closest I came to is this:

```
bins = 10
sum_of_bins = [np.sum(arr) for arr in np.array_split(followersList, bins)]
```

It uses the function `np.array_split` for splitting the large array into smaller arrays on which the summation is to be applied. You could also use `np.split`, but the latter will throw an error if `followerlist` can't be exactly divided by `bins`.