# Most efficient way to count transactions in a range by unique identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to determine the best way to count transactions in a range by identifier for a project. Below is a sample csv dataset.

```
Customer A,$1.55 ,12:01
Customer B,$12.95 ,12:02
Customer A,$28.77 ,12:03
Customer C,$35.65 ,12:04
Customer A,$11.95 ,12:05
Customer C,$7.65 ,12:06
Customer B,$55.96 ,12:07
Customer C,$44.25 ,12:08
```

If I have thousands of transaction occurring per second, and I want to know the number (count) of transactions for each customer in a range, say $0-$10, $11-20, $21-$30, $31-$40, and so on, what is the most efficient way to do this?

If I make sublists in python like

Customer A = [$1, $5, $12, $25, $18, $11]

Then I can do it pretty easily with a count function of some sort like:

```
def count_range_in_list(li, min, max):
        ctr = 0
        for x in li:
            if min <= x <= max:
                ctr += 1
        return ctr

print(count_range_in_list(Customer A, 0, 10))
```

[source: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/list/python-data-type-list-exercise-31.php ]

Just struggling with an efficient way to do this from a large dataset. Since I know my customers I could do a comparison between the transaction data and that list and try to parse it that way, then do the count by range?

Any help getting started would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary to store the customers' values, as opposed to assigning each to its own variable?

Comment: I could certainly do that, but I still think my problem persists in that I would have to find an efficient way to count the number of transactions in the desired range.

Comment: Using a multindexed dataframe shall be good here. The Customers as the first index and price range as columns

Comment: @VisheshMangia I am reviewing this now, it looks promising. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I m not a regular pandas user therefore I cant really help without a bit of practice but it might be a good idea to find related answers on SO since I don't think the docs are friendly on multiindexing part

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do an aggregation on a table, which has a couple of options. If you can get away with using dataframes then a [pandas groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation would be the easiest, but definitely not the most efficient.

You can also use binning methods. [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651218/how-to-bin-the-sum-of-list-values-in-python)

If SQL is an option it would make the operation much easier and efficient.

For example:

```sql
with customer_a as (
select * 
, if (amount < 10, 1, 0) as cat_1
, if (amount > 10 and amount < 20, 1, 0) as cat_2
from customer_transactions
where customer = 'Customer A'
)

select customer
, sum(cat_1) as cat_1_count
, sum(cat_2) as cat_2_count
from customer_a
group by 1
```