# Bin a dataframe according to two features

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data frame consisting of 4 columns; date-time, wind speed, wind speed and wind direction. I need to bin the data in wind speed channels according to wind direction (12 sectors) and for every wind speed bin (1m/s, 2m/s, 3m/s and so on) and then calculate the mean of them. It would be easy if I needed to bin only according to wind direction or wind speed. I have found the answer for it:

[binning data in python with scipy/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163334/binning-data-in-python-with-scipy-numpy)

However, I don't know how should I proceed binning according to two features.

I would appreciate it if someone has an idea.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What about rounding the values and then grouping them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe:

- Convert your directions and speeds to bin indices if they are not already. You can use `numpy.searchsorted` for that.
- Flatten the 2D bin indices using `numpy.ravel_multi_index`.
- Use `numpy.bincount` on the flattened indices, once without weights and once with the quantity you want the mean of as weights. Then take the quotient to obtain the means. Optionally, cleanup any `nan`s resulting from empty bins, (`nan` is technically the correct answer but may be undesirable nonetheless).