# Rebinning a 1-D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, binning

Don't know if this is a duplicate, but I haven't managed to find it.

I want to do something so simple to say, it hurts that I cannot figure it out.

I have a test array in 1D:

```
A = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

What I want is a function, call it "rebin", that will do the following:

```
A = rebin(A, 4)
```

where the 4 is the length of the 1D array to output. The output I'd like to get is as follows:

```
print(A) >>> [val1, val2, val3, val4]
```

where valn is the new value at the new nth bin as determined by some interpolation on the original array.

I have this code, adapted from IDL:

```
def rebin(a, newdims, method='linear', centre=False, minusone=False):
    '''Arbitrary resampling of source array to new dimension sizes.
    Currently only supports maintaining the same number of dimensions.
    To use 1-D arrays, first promote them to shape (x,1).

    Uses the same parameters and creates the same co-ordinate lookup points
    as IDL''s congrid routine, which apparently originally came from a VAX/VMS
    routine of the same name.

    method:
    neighbour - closest value from original data
    nearest and linear - uses n x 1-D interpolations using
                         scipy.interpolate.interp1d
    (see Numerical Recipes for validity of use of n 1-D interpolations)
    spline - uses ndimage.map_coordinates

    centre:
    True - interpolation points are at the centres of the bins
    False - points are at the front edge of the bin

    minusone:
    For example- inarray.shape = (i,j) & new dimensions = (x,y)
    False - inarray is resampled by factors of (i/x) * (j/y)
    True - inarray is resampled by(i-1)/(x-1) * (j-1)/(y-1)
    This prevents extrapolation one element beyond bounds of input array.
    '''
    if not a.dtype in [n.float64, n.float32]:
        a = n.cast[float](a)

    m1 = n.cast[int](minusone)
    ofs = n.cast[int](centre) * 0.5
    old = n.array( a.shape )
    ndims = len( a.shape )
    if len( newdims ) != ndims:
        print "[congrid] dimensions error. " \
              "This routine currently only support " \
              "rebinning to the same number of dimensions."
        return None
    newdims = n.asarray( newdims, dtype=float )
    dimlist = []

    if method == 'neighbour':
        for i in range( ndims ):
            base = n.indices(newdims)[i]
            dimlist.append( (old[i] - m1) / (newdims[i] - m1) \
                            * (base + ofs) - ofs )
        cd = n.array( dimlist ).round().astype(int)
        newa = a[list( cd )]
        return newa

    elif method in ['nearest','linear']:
        # calculate new dims
        for i in range( ndims ):
            base = n.arange( newdims[i] )
            dimlist.append( (old[i] - m1) / (newdims[i] - m1) \
                            * (base + ofs) - ofs )
        # specify old dims
        olddims = [n.arange(i, dtype = n.float) for i in list( a.shape )]

        # first interpolation - for ndims = any
        mint = scipy.interpolate.interp1d( olddims[-1], a, kind=method )
        newa = mint( dimlist[-1] )

        trorder = [ndims - 1] + range( ndims - 1 )
        for i in range( ndims - 2, -1, -1 ):
            newa = newa.transpose( trorder )

            mint = scipy.interpolate.interp1d( olddims[i], newa, kind=method )
            newa = mint( dimlist[i] )

        if ndims > 1:
            # need one more transpose to return to original dimensions
            newa = newa.transpose( trorder )

        return newa
    elif method in ['spline']:
        oslices = [ slice(0,j) for j in old ]
        oldcoords = n.ogrid[oslices]
        nslices = [ slice(0,j) for j in list(newdims) ]
        newcoords = n.mgrid[nslices]

        newcoords_dims = range(n.rank(newcoords))
        #make first index last
        newcoords_dims.append(newcoords_dims.pop(0))
        newcoords_tr = newcoords.transpose(newcoords_dims)
        # makes a view that affects newcoords

        newcoords_tr += ofs

        deltas = (n.asarray(old) - m1) / (newdims - m1)
        newcoords_tr *= deltas

        newcoords_tr -= ofs

        newa = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(a, newcoords)
        return newa
    else:
        print "Congrid error: Unrecognized interpolation type.\n", \
              "Currently only \'neighbour\', \'nearest\',\'linear\',", \
              "and \'spline\' are supported."
        return None
```

Using their own advice, I reshaped all my arrays as (n, 1), giving them each two dimensions. However, in the method above, `olddims[-1]` has a length of 1 (attributed to the 1 given in the shape). This produces the following error from SciPy when trying `scipy.interpolate.interp1d( olddims[-1], a, kind=method )`:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 543, in __init__
    "least %d entries" % minval)
ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 2 entries
```

I really thought this would be more trivial than this and I've probably needlessly overcomplicated it. Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [binning data in python with scipy/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163334/binning-data-in-python-with-scipy-numpy)

Comment: I had a look but I don't think it's the same thing? Or maybe I'm missing some logic?