# How to get an index of an item within a range in python list?

Tags: python

(Re-edited)
For example, I have a list-like array:

```
l = [0.3, 2.3, 3.1, 4.5] # value can be any numeric type
```

Then given a number `1.2`, as it is between `0.3 and 2.3`, index `1` should be returned, and given a number `3.3`, which is between `3.1 and 4.5`, index `3` should be returned, for value less than `0.3`, should return index `0`, etc.

Basically for whatever input value, depends on the bin it falls into, return the index of that bin.

I hope not use `if else` statement, as the number of items in the list could be huge.

I guess the question should have been asked somewhere, but I just can't locate it.

(BTW, I actually remember there is a built-in function in `numpy` does the trick, but I can't recall anymore ...)

Comment: and what's expected for `1.5`?

Comment: How about rounding?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `1.5` should be in `1 and 2` as well

Comment: Is the rounding strategy toward zero like in `round(n)` or toward negative infinity like in floor division `n // 1`?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this? [binning data in python with scipy/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6163334/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea Exactly `np.digitize` is what I am looking for, thanks for the quick response!  I used this function before, but forgot that...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l.index(round(1.2))
0
>>> l.index(round(3.3))
2
```

Assuming normal rounding rules.

Comment: I am looking for more general case, the values in the list does not have to be `int`

Answer (score 0):

The floor function from math library can also be used.

```
>>> l.index(floor(1.2))
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers assumed that we have order step 1 array. in general form you can use something like this:

```
# for 1.5
l.index(max(x for x in l if x < 1.5))
# output: 0
# for 2.5
l.index(max(x for x in l if x < 2.5))
# output: 1
```

**Caution**: I assumed that there is no repeat in data and it sorted